# iFrame contentWindow LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, iframe, lwc-dom

I have a LWC with an iframe inside.

The iframe's src is a URL from an external system that loads a Document Editor.

I want to access the contentWindow of the iFrame.

```
var editor= this.template.querySelector('iframe').contentWindow;
```

When I debug it it returns:
`SecureIFrameContentWindow: [object Object]{ key: {"namespace":"c"} }`
and when I json.stringify it it returns `{}`

And also in the logs there's a Warning
`Warning: Parent window properties and functions are not accesible. Cross domain security problem detected. Editor is unable to call external functions.`

I think that that's the reason why we can't access the contentWindow of the iFrame

Comment: CORS is going to fight you on this because the frame is around an external domain, unless you can find a configuration that works for your use-case. What is the reason for grabbing the `contentWindow` property off of the `iframe` in the first place?

Comment: We need to get the contentWindow because all javascript method to interact with the document editor is there.